# Why aren't my notifications getting created in my BroadcastReceiver class?

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to create a notification on an incoming call in my class CallReceiver.

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
            showNotification();


        }
        else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            showToast(context, "Call ended");
        }
    }
```

I've tried a lot of different ways, but nothing worked for me.

This was one of my solutions - using a showNotification-method:

```
    private void showNotification(Context context){
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder)
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("Notification")
                        .setContentText("This is a notification");
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,mBuilder.build());

    }
```

Comment: Ok. But what goes wrong? Errors? Exceptions? Logcat.

Comment: showNotification(); AND private void showNotification(Context context) do not match.

Comment: use `showNotification(context);`, you have to pass expected argument.